# Swagger complex response model with dynamic key value hash maps

Tags: hashmap, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm struggling with the syntax of swagger to describe a response type. What I'm trying to model is a hash map with dynamic keys and values. This is needed to allow a localization. The languages may vary, but english should always be provided.

The response would look like this in JSON:

```
{
  id: "1234",
  name: {
    en: "english text",
    de: "Deutscher Text"
  }
}
```

My first try was looking like that, but I have no idea how to write the part for the name. AdditionalProperties seems to be a key, but I can't wrap my head around it. Also the requirement for english text is a mystery to me in this syntax and the example also does not seem to work as expected. It generates an empty $folded: in the UI.

```
delayReason:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      description: Identifier for a delay reason.
    name:
      type: object
      additionalProperties: 
        type: string
  required: [id, name]
  example:
    id: 123
    name: 
      en: english text
      de: Deutscher Text
```

But this produces: 
[image: swagger editor result]

There is also no clue in this that the result will have a language code as a key and the text as the value of the hash map.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The part with "additionalProperties" are always using string keys and thus are neglegted would be a good hint in the documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you are running into at least three separate bugs and/or limitations:

1. Neither Swagger-Editor nor Swagger-UI provides any indication in the documentation format to show that `additionalProperties` are allowed in your object schema. So even where you've used `additionalProperties` correctly, and it's recognized by the Swagger parser, these documentation formats won't show it.  You need to add this detail to your schema `description`, so users understand that they can include additional string properties.
   **Note:** You probably also expect the additional property names to follow a convention, e.g. a two-letter language code.  While full JSON Schema lets you specify this with `patternProperties`, unfortunately, that's not supported in Swagger's schema object.  So again, you should specify that in your schema description.
2. The Swagger-Editor format sometimes shows this odd "folded:" property. I saw it this morning, now strangely I cannot reproduce it.  It might have been hot-fixed today.  But regardless, it's certainly a bug, and specific to Swagger-Editor.  It should not affect your downstream code generation, nor the standard Swagger-UI that presents your API documentation to client developers at runtime. (Though the documentation pane in Swagger-Editor looks similar to Swagger-UI, it is a separate implementation.)
3. There are some subtle but significant limitations to the use of `additionalProperties` in Swagger. While [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen)'s example doesn't show any visible errors, in fact, the Swagger parser will fail to process this schema correctly; it will ignore either your explicitly declared `en` property, or will ignore `additionalProperties`!

This last issue comes down to a design flaw in Swagger-Model, one of the core components used throughout the Swagger Java stack (including Swagger-Codegen). Schemas defined in certain contexts can work with a combination of `properties` and `additionalProperties`.  But schemas defined in other contexts cannot.

We've [documented this in detail here](https://support.reprezen.com/support/solutions/articles/6000162892-support-for-additionalproperties-in-swagger-2-0-schemas).

The good news: with a small tweak, we can make Helen's example work correctly. We just need to extract the nested object schema into its own top-level definition.  I'll call it `LocalizedName`:

```yaml
definitions:
  delayReason:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: Identifier for a delay reason.
      name:
        $ref: '#/definitions/LocalizedName'
    required: [id, name]
    example:
      id: '123' # Note the quotes to force the value as a string
      name:
        en: English text
        de: Deutscher Text

  LocalizedName:
    type: object
    description: A hashmap with language code as a key and the text as the value.
    properties:
      en:
        type: string
        description: English text of a delay reason.
    required: [en]
    additionalProperties:
      type: string
```

Answer (score 38):

Your usage of `additionalProperties` is correct and your model is correct.

#### additionalProperties

In Swagger/OpenAPI, hashmap keys are assumed to be strings, so the key type is not defined explicitly. `additionalProperties` define the type of hashmap values. So, this schema

```yaml
type: object
additionalProperties: 
  type: string
```

defines a string-to-string map such as:

```json
{
  "en": "English text",
  "de": "Deutscher Text"
}
```

If you needed a string-to-integer map such as:

```json
{
  "en": 5,
  "de": 3
}
```

you would define `additionalProperties` as having value type `integer`:

```yaml
type: object
additionalProperties: 
  type: integer
```

#### Required key in a hashmap

To define `en` as a required key in the hashmap:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
  en:
    type: string
required: [en]
additionalProperties: 
  type: string
```

#### Complete example

```yaml
definitions:
  delayReason:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: Identifier for a delay reason.
      name:
        type: object
        description: A hashmap with language code as a key and the text as the value.
        properties:
          en:
            type: string
            description: English text of a delay reason.
        required: [en]
        additionalProperties: 
          type: string
    required: [id, name]
    example:
      id: '123' # Note the quotes to force the value as a string
      name: 
        en: English text
        de: Deutscher Text
```

> There is also no clue in this that the result will have a language code as a key and the text as the value of the hash map.

Things like that can be documented verbally in the `description`.

> the example also does not seem to work as expected. It generates an empty $folded: in the UI.

Not sure what the problem was with your original spec, but the spec above is valid and looks fine in the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io).

[image: Model schema in Swagger Editor]

Answer (score -1):

If you're still in the design stage, instead of using dynamic keys, you can push all the other language references in an array with structure like:

```
{
"launguage":"en"
"text":"Hello World"
}
```

That would simplify things a lot, and since you're not relying on `additionalProperties`, your generated client libraries will find this easier to digest.

Comment: This changes the functional constraints: With this design there could be two objects for 'en' in the payload, which could be something worth designing out of the API, and it's better IMO to do that naturally than through documenting logical constraints.