# Custom data type for YAML list

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I'm using YAML for api documentation in OpenAPI 3.0. For one field the data type should be a List of Items.

Is there any way to do it like this?

```
order-info-list:
      type: List<#/components/schemas/Item>
```

This is the Item schema.

```
components:

  schemas:
    Item:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          description: ID of item
        name:
          type: string
          description: Name of item
        quantity:
          type: integer
          description: Item quantity
        unit-price:
          type: integer
          description: >-
            Item unit price in cents
              Same currency code & conversion exponent applies
        additional-detail:
          type: Map<string, string>
      xml:
        name: Item
```

Comment: Also, in `additional-detail`, the `type` should be `type: object` with `properties: {type: string}` - see [Swagger editor dictionary parameter definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41867499/113116).

Comment: Helen - Thanks for pointing it out