# How to create swagger documentation for dynamic request/response

Tags: asp.net, typescript, .net-core, swagger

We have an API application which is driven dynamically based on SQL defined metadata. This API app is a reporting application and the report is driven by what kind of request is passed into the API. This means if JSON request is passed like this -
ex 1

```
 {
    "Field1": "Value1"
    "GroupBy": ["GroupByValue1", "GroupByValue2"]
    }
```

Then it gives below resultset -

```
{
"GroupByValue1": "SomeValue1"
"GroupByValue2": "SomeValue2"
... other fields based on GroupBy1 and GroupBy2
}
```

ex 2

```
{
"Field1": "Value1"
"GroupBy": ["GroupByValue3"]
}
```

Then it gives below resultset -

```
{
"GroupByValue3": "SomeValue1"
... other fields based on GroupBy3
}
```

So the mapping of request v/s fields for that request is defined in the SQL database.
And we need to generate swagger documentation for this kind of dynamic requests. So my question is since we use swashbuckle for swagger documentation, we have to give it specific resultset based on the request being passed. Now we have APIs to give us those request/resultset relationship, but is there a way to generate documentation completely dynamically based on this API (using c# code or typescript) that gives us request/resultset relationship.

Comment: Do these links answer your question? [Freeform subobject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41606152/113116), [Swagger complex response model with dynamic key value hash maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41097913/113116), [Swagger Editor dictionary parameter definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41867499/113116)

Comment: To add to what @Helen said, you need to implement an IOperationFilter that modifies the operation schema to match what OpenAPI spec requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dynamic Swagger documentation using `IDocumentFilter`.
We also use dynamic SQL metadata at this [example](https://github.com/JJConsulting/JJMasterData/blob/main/src/Plugins/Swagger.AspNetCore/DataDictionaryDocumentFilter.cs).

Comment: The example url is no longer available. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Fixed the link my friend